# JS Prevent XSS but allow HTML URL

Tags: javascript, xss

I have an Angular 1 app, with a form input used for creating site notifications.

A user can enter a full url `http://example.com` or they can also enter a path within the application `/foo/barboo`

However, an attacker could also enter `javascript:alert(1);//` and when the notification link is pressed, the JS will fire.

Is it possible to encode this input but still allow url's to be treated as such?

Comment: Why do you need them to be able to use relative links? This would make everything a lot easier

Comment: You could check the input with a regex.

Comment: I'm not privy to the design decisions I'm afraid, this is something I have been asked to work on that is 5 or 6 years old. I would change the whole thing if I could

Comment: @pgGriff did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex that'll match both URIs starting with a schema (http/https/ftp) and "relative" URIs starting with a slash:

```
/((\/[\w-.]+)(\/[\w-.]+)*\/?)|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/gi
```

```js
const re = /((\/[\w-.]+)(\/[\w-.]+)*\/?)|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/gi

console.log("https://example.com/foo/bar".match(re)[0]); //matches 

console.log("/foo/bar/baz/bim".match(re)[0]); //matches

console.log("javascript:alert('xss');//".match(re)); //doesn't match (null)

console.log("/foo/bar/baz/bim.html".match(re)[0]); //matches

console.log("https://example.com/foo/bar-api.php?e=mc2".match(re)[0]); //matches
```

#### **[regexr.com](https://regexr.com/3qfre)**